# Can an identity element be variable?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a×b := | a + b | $ where $a,b$ are real numbers, then the obvious identity element is zero, but $e=-2x$ meets the condition that $e×x = x×e = x$, however, this is not a fixed member of the real numbers. Is this considered an identity element? Or do identity elements have to be a specific member of the set, as opposed to variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

First of all, unless you remove the absolute value bars, 0 is *not* an identity element, and indeed there is no identity (think about it . . .).

Second, yes, the identity element of a set $A$ with respect to an operation $*$ has to be an element *of that set $A$*. We can put $(A, *)$ inside a larger algebraic structure, $B$, and maybe $*$ has an identity element in $B$; but that's not an identity element in $A$. Moreover, you'd need to tell me how these new objects - the things in $B$ but not $A$ - interact with *each other*, as well as just with $A$.

All you've shown is that for each element of the set there is something which it absorbs (actually you haven't even shown that, see my first point). But this is not the same as there being an element which is absorbed by everything, that is, an identity element.

Comment: You are correct, I was thinking of the positive reals when I proved $0$ to be an identity element. Thank you for answering my question, in addition to correcting my mistake in the example.

Comment: In that case my other points still stand.

Comment: Yes, this answered my question thouroughly.

Answer (score 1):

A set with this binary operation will not have an identity element because if you pick $a$ to be a negative number, then there exists no $b$ such that $|a + b| = a$.

Answer (score 1):

So what you are in fact implying is that all of the elements of the given ring (or field, or group) are in fact identities? However, this is clearly false, since an identity attached to an operator is unique by definition.

An identity is an element by itself, and only depends on how addition/ multiplication / transformations are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Let e= `minus two elephants`, x=`one elephant`. Are you still thinking that e is an identity element on reals?

(Sorry for an absurd example, but I hope that it helps to understand the problem).

Comment: You are correct, I was thinking of the positive reals when I proved $0$ to be an identity element. Which then makes $2x$ not part of the set in the first place.

Comment: The elephants seem... irrelephant? And I do mean that seriously – it's possible to read this answer as arguing that you can't add elephants and real numbers, which would be beside the point since $e$ and $x$ are presumably real numbers.